# Assembly program no debugging symbols found in GDB

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

So my first foray into Assembly. I have a demo program that is just setting some values and then moving them between memory locations and registers.
Simples.

The problem is when I try to analyse the program in `gdb` I get this error:

`Reading symbols from DataTypes... (no debugging symbols found)... done`.

GDB is configures as `i686-linux-gnu` and running on Kali Linux in a Windows 10 hosted VMWare instance.
`uname -a: Linux Kali 4.17.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.17.8-1kali1 (2018-07-04) i686 GNU Linux`.

My Code...

```
# Demo program to show how to use Data types and MOVx instructions 

.data 

    HelloWorld:
        .ascii "Hello World!"

    ByteLocation:
        .byte 10

    Int32:
        .int 2
    Int16:
        .short 3
    Float:
        .float 10.23

    IntegerArray:
        .int 10,20,30,40,50


.bss
    .comm LargeBuffer, 10000

.text 

    .globl _start

    _start:

        nop

        # 1. MOV immediate value into register 

        movl $10, %eax

        # 2. MOV immediate value into memory location 

        movw $50, Int16

        # 3. MOV data between registers 

        movl %eax, %ebx


        # 4. MOV data from memory to register 

        movl Int32, %eax 

        # 5. MOV data from register to memory 

        movb $3, %al
        movb %al, ByteLocation

        # 6. MOV data into an indexed memory location 
        # Location is decided by BaseAddress(Offset, Index, DataSize)
        # Offset and Index must be registers, Datasize can be a numerical value 

        movl $0, %ecx
        movl $2, %edi
        movl $22, IntegerArray(%ecx,%edi , 4)

        # 7. Indirect addressing using registers 

        movl $Int32, %eax
        movl (%eax), %ebx

        movl $9, (%eax)



        # Exit syscall to exit the program 

        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
```

Comment: That's not an error as such and gdb can still work. But indeed it's more convenient if you assemble with debug info (lines and symbols). You did not show the command you use but for example `as -g` or `gcc -g -nostdlib` could work.

Comment: @Jester `-g` flag sorted it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as per suggestion by [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester)

I reran the compilation with `as` using the `-g` flag.

`as -g -o DataTypes.o DataTypes.s`

Linked
`ld -o DataTypes DataTypes.o`

Ran GDB

`gdb ./DataTypes`